# how to change the color of link when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to change the link colour onclick, the links are ajax based, i tried a lot but didn't get success how can i change the change it, request action is going on this page.

```
        <div class="topheading-right">
        <span>
            <?php echo $this->Manager->link('Archived Events', array('a'));?>
        </span>
        <?php echo $this->Manager->link('View All', array(''));?>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='events-event_list' class='dashboard-<?php echo __l($product_name);?>s'>
    <?php echo $this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'events', 'action'=>'view_event_list', $is_archive), array('return'));?>
</div>
```

How can i do that? thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the generated HTML, not the PHP code.

Comment: the generated html is <div id="" class="topheading-right">
<span>
<a id="link-790271931" href="/events/view_dashboard/a">Archived Events</a>
</span>
<a id="link-1351686068" href="/events/view_dashboard">View All</a>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

If it's an AJAX link, you can't use the `:visited` pseudoselector.

Instead, use:

```
 $('a').live('click',function(){this.style.css.color='red'})
```

or something similar

Comment: @usii: Umm...that's up to you... Your question was how to make the links change color once clicked. You didn't ask us to make the links for you. Be more clear in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('a[id^="link-"]').on('click',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var Obj = $(this);
   Obj.css('color','red');
   var href = Obj.attr('href');
   //ajax call with url href
});
```

Comment: how can i make the proper link to do that?

Comment: @usii i seen your comment and according to that i updated my code no need to change link my code automatically select links that id starts with "link-"..try it

Comment: nice but when i clicked the link and the page will load the red color is not appear, but when i stay click on the link then the red appear, i want to show red colour after click and remain block.

Comment: @usii page is load mean redirecting..?

Comment: same request action is call on both links

Comment: hummmm so that is the reason why your links color is not showing change after page load...to do that you should use jQuery.Cookies plugin to check for cookies set and according to that cookie value set link color changed.

Answer (score 0):

should be something like this

```
 $('a').on('click',function(){
     $(this).css('color','red');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers (even in IE10) if You will set `a:active` pseudo class You will get this result without JavaScript:

```
a:active{ color: red; }
```

You can also asign othere attributes.

Comment: if i used pseudo class then the all active link will be red man

Comment: Yes, but only one link can be active at a time